# Why are all my _values saved as string and not float?

Tags: java, influxdb

Humidity and temperature values are saved as strings in the DB. I am not getting errors or exceptions while writing the POJO to the InfluxDB. Is there a way to fix this?

```
    @Override
    public void process(Event event) {
        try {
            WriteApiBlocking writeApi = client.getWriteApiBlocking();
            writeApi.writeMeasurement(WritePrecision.S, factory.getSensorDTO(SensorType.DHT11, event));
        } catch (InfluxException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Check if the database service is running.");
        }
    }
```

```
@Measurement(name = "DHT11")
public class DHT11 implements Sensor {
    private final SensorType type = SensorType.DHT11;

    @Column(tag = true)
    private int deviceId;

    @Column
    private float humidity;

    @Column
    private float temperature;

    public DHT11(Event event) {
        TempEvent e = (TempEvent) event.getEvent();
        try {
            this.temperature = e.getTemperature();
            this.humidity = e.getHumidity();
            this.deviceId = e.getDeviceId();
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            npe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public SensorType getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

https://community.influxdata.com/t/unable-to-use-type-float-solved/7157

Answer: Use a `double`.

The odd thing is that `float` vs `Float` has very different behavior. I thought I would write this because someone may stumble upon this later on and waste time. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

I submitted a bug here: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-java/issues/293